# Java handling exceptions functional programming

Tags: java, exception, functional-programming, serversocket, functional-interface

I have this piece of code:

```
private void handleReceivedMessage(String m) throws IOException {
    switch(m) {
        case "ping":
            // code block
            ping();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("message not understood");
    }

}
public DataServer(int port) throws IOException {
        server = new Server(port, this::handleReceivedMessage);
        server.acceptClient();
}
```

now I get the error at the line this::handleReceivedMessage:
Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException

How do I solve this? It's clear that the handleReceivedMessage functions does throw an IOException

Comment: Wrap it in an `UncheckedIOException` in `handleReceivedMessage` and remove the `throws IOException`?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with wrapping a function with an exception? (I'm pretty new to Java)

Comment: Can you provide info about the Server class, at least about its constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more, I'd try using a try/catch statement specifically to catch the exception being thrown as Olivier is suggesting. If may I ask, why aren't you using try/catch for error checking?